# How to observe the value of a global variable and act on a change within the ViewController

Tags: swift

I'm using universal links in my iOS app and can successfully store a URL value within the app as a global variable. This is done early in the app delegate. This works from start up and when the app is re-opened from the background.

This URL is then passed to a WKWebView as the source URL.

The problem is the ViewController for the WKWebView is already loaded and doesn't detect the new URL until I segue out and back.

I have made a very ugly section of code that work but is not good enough for production. It monitors the change of the variable off the main thread but is done with a repeat loop and a sleep of 1 second to avoid over running the CPU.

What is the correct way of making a segue within a view controller when the value of a global variable is not equal to its default?

I have looked a willset and didset. But as my variable is defined outside of the view controller class I cannot perform a segue.

```
// home made loop to look for a change in universal link
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
     repeat
      {
       sleep(1) // save CPU
      }
     while universalOverrideURL == "none"
     DispatchQueue.main.sync {
     print("S E G U E  I S  N E E D E D !")
   }
}
```

Is there a better method I can apply that respects the CPU?

Comment: “But as my variable is defined outside of the view controller class I cannot perform a segue.” That is where you are wrong. Your job is to rearrange the view controller hierarchy to respond to the deep link. You can do that from the app delegate.

Comment: Well you weren't kidding about the code being ugly. Is there a particular reason this needs to be a global variable? Is there a reason why this view controller can't be injected with the URL at its instantiation? Your view controller hierarchy may need a revision.

Comment: And never use global variables please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.  The iOS native way is to use NotificationCenter:

```
//Make your custom notification
extension Notification.Name {
    static let myCustomValueUpdated = Notification.Name("myCustomValueUpdated")
}

//Post the notification when you the value
NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: .myCustomValueUpdated, object: nil, userInfo: ["value": someNewValue]))

//Subscribe everywhere that needs to be interested in UserDefaults changes
let token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .myCustomValueUpdated, object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
    if let value = notification.userInfo["value"] {
        //Do stuff with new value here
    }
}
```

You could also consider making a service to wrap the value the value that you are changing and then use the observer pattern to allow other objects to subscribe to changes in that value.  I tend to prefer this solution since its 1) testable and mockable, 2) strongly typed, 3) Moves stuff out of your app delegate, but if you don't care about any of that just use the NotificationCenter, because its the least work and a well understood apple pattern.

Comment: Minor observation, but I think you meant `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .myCustomValueUpdated, object: nil, userInfo: ["value": someNewValue])` and `if let value = notification.userInfo?["value"] { ... }` (note the `?`).

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works perfectly, comment about adding a ? or ! after userInfo is correct. Extension section added to the main view controller, notification post to the app delegate and check for update to the view did load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate to notify your ViewController.

This is an interface of delegate:

```
@protocol UniversalOverrideURLObserver

func onURLChanged(url: String) -> Void

@end
```

Your ViewController can implement this interface:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,  UniversalOverrideURLObserver {

}
```

Then, your code, which instantiates ViewController, can do smth like this:

```
func addObserver(observer: UniversalOverrideURLObserver) -> Void {
    self.observer = observer
}

func funcWhereValueChanges() {
    // HERE your url changed    
    self.observer.onURLChanged(url: newURL)
}

func funcWhereViewControllerShown() {
    // HERE you are ready to present ViewController
    let vc = ViewController()
    self.addObserver(vc)
}
```